# why not include styles for element in textarea with ckeditor?

Tags: css, styles, ckeditor

Good day.

I use ckeditor on my page

Code:

```
<textarea class="ckeditor" cols="80" name="header" rows="5" id="ursopr" required>
 </textarea>
```

And i have styles:

```
.about span {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 20px;
}

.about {
    color: #feffff;
}

.about {
    color: #feffff;
}

.about b {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: normal;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

For ckeditor not delete class in `ul` in config.js i add rows:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {

    config.allowedContent = true;
};
```

but after add this rows i see that in textarea(iframe ckeditor) not include styles for elements.

**But in textarea with ckeditor i get:**

[image: image1]
[image: image2]

Tell me please how include styles for elements in textarea with ckeditor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
config.contentsCss = 'path/to/style.css';
```

I can't test this right now, it's from memory so I hope it helps!

See [config.contentsCss docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-contentsCss).

Comment: yes> i want  close question, but you say already)) but thanks)

Answer (score 0):

Seems do not exist a css rule defined for you class "ckeditor". You have to add "ckeditor" class in the same css file where the rule for "about" class is defined.

some like this:

```
.ckeditor
{
color: blue;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but it not need me. me need include css file, not only one style.